# Efficiently creating lists in Python due to dynamic variable

Tags: python, algorithm, design-patterns, refactoring

I'm using [Keras](https://keras.io/) to build an [LSTM recurrent neural network](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/). My code is working well, but could do with a serious refactoring. I am forecasting time series values, and depending on the window-size I want to predict, I end up writing code that seems far too specific to that window-size, i.e. it is hard to cater for lots of different sizes.

I split my dataset into train & test sets

```py
print "Dataset length: %d" % len(dataset)
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
print "Train length: %d, Test length: %d" % (len(train), len(test))
```

> Dataset length: 1826 Train length: 1223, Test length: 603

Then for both `train` and `test` I need to create an `X` which is the input, and a `Y` which is the output (what I am trying to predict)

```
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1, predict_steps=1):

    dataX, dataY = [], []

    for i in range(dataset.shape[0] - look_back - predict_steps):
        dataX.append(dataset[i:(i + look_back), 0])
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back:i + look_back + predict_steps, 0])

    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

look_back = 10
predict_steps = 5
input_dim = look_back + 1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back=look_back, predict_steps=predict_steps)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back=look_back, predict_steps=predict_steps)
print "trainX shape: %s, trainY shape: %s" % (trainX.shape, trainY.shape,)
```

> trainX shape: (1208, 10), trainY shape: (1208, 5)

If I want to predict 5 timesteps ahead then my predictions, stored in the variable `trainY`, will take the form `[[t+6, t+7, t+8, t+9, t+10], [t+7, t+8, t+9, t+10, t+11]]`, i.e.

```
prediction 1    [t+6,   t+7,    t+8,    t+9,    t+10]
prediction 2    [t+7,   t+8,    t+9,    t+10,   t+11]
prediction 3    [t+8,   t+9,    t+10,   t+11,   t+12]
prediction 4    [t+9,   t+10,   t+11,   t+12,   t+13]
prediction 5    [t+10,  t+11,   t+12,   t+13,   t+14]
```

[image]

Now if I want to get these values back in a logical sequence, i.e. `t+6, t+7, t+8,...,t+14`
I am using this code

```py
output = trainY
output_plot = np.array([])
output_plot = np.append(output_plot, output[0][0])
output_plot = np.append(output_plot, np.mean([output[0][1], output[1][0]]))
output_plot = np.append(output_plot, np.mean([output[0][2], output[1][1], output[2][0]]))
output_plot = np.append(output_plot, np.mean([output[0][3], output[1][2], output[2][1], output[3][0]]))

for i in range (len(output) - predict_steps + 1):
    tmp = np.mean([output[i][4], output[i+1][3], output[i+2][2], output[i+3][1], output[i+4][0]])
    output_plot = np.append(output_plot, tmp)
```

My problem arises when I want to extend the prediction window out to say 10 timesteps. Then I manually extend the preceding code as follows

```py
output = trainY
output_plot = np.array([])
output_plot = np.append(output_plot, output[0][0])
output_plot = np.append(output_plot, np.mean([output[0][1], output[1][0]]))
output_plot = np.append(output_plot, np.mean([output[0][2], output[1][1], output[2][0]]))
output_plot = np.append(output_plot, np.mean([output[0][3], output[1][2], output[2][1], output[3][0]]))
output_plot = np.append(output_plot, np.mean([output[0][4], output[1][3], output[2][2], output[3][1], output[4][0]]))
output_plot = np.append(output_plot, np.mean([output[0][5], output[1][4], output[2][3], output[3][2], output[4][1], output[5][0]]))
output_plot = np.append(output_plot, np.mean([output[0][6], output[1][5], output[2][4], output[3][3], output[4][2], output[5][1], output[6][0]]))
output_plot = np.append(output_plot, np.mean([output[0][7], output[1][6], output[2][5], output[3][4], output[4][3], output[5][2], output[6][1], output[7][0]]))
output_plot = np.append(output_plot, np.mean([output[0][8], output[1][7], output[2][6], output[3][5], output[4][4], output[5][3], output[6][2], output[7][1], output[8][0]]))


for i in range (len(output) - predict_steps + 1):
    tmp = np.mean([output[i][9], output[i+1][8], output[i+2][7], output[i+3][6], output[i+4][5], output[i+5][4], output[i+6][3], output[i+7][2], output[i+8][1], output[i+9][0]])
    output_plot = np.append(output_plot, tmp)
```

While this works, it is horrendously inefficient. How can I best refactor these steps to make the code more amenable to a wider range of prediction windows? Also, my question title could do with some improvement, so please edit away!

Comment: In the first part of your code samples, it appears that you're simply taking the mean of each diagonal above the main antidiagonal of a square 2D-list. But I don't understand what your loop is trying to do. Isn't `len(output)` always equal to `predict_steps`? Wouldn't the first line inside your loop raise an `IndexError` if `i` is anything other than `0`?

Comment: No output can be any length really, depending on the dataset, e.g. it might go from `t+6,...,t+500` but that outputted is predicted in windows with a length equal to `predict_steps`. Does that make sense? Or will I update the question with an example of what I mean?

Comment: But `output` is still a square, symmetric matrix in the form of a 2D list, right? Can you show an example where, say, `predict_steps` is `3`, and `len(output)` is `5`? What does `output` look like, and what does your loop like then?

Comment: I have updated showing examples from the code I'm currently working on where `predict_steps` is `5`. Hopefully that helps clarify things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: I know nothing about your neural network problem, I'm just addressing your coding/array-traversal problem)

Taking the diagonals of a matrix can be done with loops--you just have to adjust the parameters of the loop to the appropriate dimensions. The following code is a simplified mock-up in pure Python of what you're trying to accomplish from what I understand about the shape of your data.

```
from pprint import pprint

def create_mock_data(n):
    return [[100 + i] for i in range(n)]

def create_dataset(dataset, look_back = 1, predict_steps = 1):
    X, Y = [], []

    for i in range(len(dataset) - look_back - predict_steps):
        X.append([row[0] for row in dataset[i : i+look_back]])
        Y.append([row[0] for row in dataset[i+look_back : i+look_back+predict_steps]])

    return X, Y

def antidiagonals(a):
    m, n = len(a), len(a[0])

    for k in range(0, n):
        yield [a[k-i][i] for i in range(k + 1)]

    for k in range(n, m):
        yield [a[k-i][i] for i in range(n)]

def pp(label, x):
    print('---', label, '---')
    pprint(x, width = 108)
    print()

def test(n, look_back, predict_steps):
    print('=' * 72)
    print('n =', n)
    print('look_back =', look_back)
    print('predict_steps =', predict_steps)
    print()

    dataset = create_mock_data(n)
    pp('dataset', dataset)

    X, Y = create_dataset(dataset, look_back, predict_steps)
    pp('X', X)
    pp('Y', Y)

    diagonals = list(antidiagonals(Y))
    pp('diagonals of Y', diagonals)

    print()

test(50, look_back = 10, predict_steps = 5)
test(50, look_back = 10, predict_steps = 10)
# test(50, look_back = 15, predict_steps = 10)
```

Note that:

- I used Python lists instead of numpy arrays, so please correct me if I misinterpreted your array indexing, especially in the `create_dataset` function.
- For simplicity, I skipped the part where you split the original dataset into training and test datasets.

The main code of interest is in the `antidiagonals` function. For each row of an `MxN` matrix, it yields the rising diagonal starting from that row's first element. The first loop yields the first `N` diagonals, which all have differing lengths. The second loop yields the next `M-N` diagonals, all of which have `N` elements. When you run the code above, you can inspect the output for the mock `Y` array and its diagonals.

Assuming that these are the correct series of data you wish to add to your `output_plot`, you just have to modify the function to operate on numpy arrays and take the mean of each diagonal.  Then you should be able to adjust the prediction window without duplicating much code.

Let me know if this is or isn't in line with what you're going for.

Comment: That works excellently, thank you. For some reason when I implemented it like this I lost a small degree of precision in the numbers being returned, which I rectified in `antidiagonal` loops with `yield np.mean([a[k-i][i] for i in range(k + 1)], dtype=np.float64)`.